# How to set the height of a child view of a relative layout as a percentage of the total screen height

Tags: android

I have a main layout that I make relative so I can set a view to align at the bottom of the layout. The problem is that I want to set the width of the view as a percentage using layout gravity, but I am unable to do this as relative layouts do not support layout gravity.

How can I set the height of a child view of a relative layout as a percentage of the total screen height?

**edit**

I already tried using linear layout, but I cannot use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with a linear layout. The whole point is that the view needs to be at the bottom of the screen, but with the height as a percentage which I can't do with lay out gravity. It's a catch 22. What is the solution? Resort to programmatic settings?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<View android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try using a LinearLayout and setting the weight.

Comment: I did, but I cannot use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with a linear layout. The whole point is that the view needs to be at the bottom of the screen, not underneath the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and assign weights as required.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I was unable to set view to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` If you can show the code, I will mark this question as asnwered.

Comment: Then tell me the percentage you need for each view

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the following Layout File as I created one in my Screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The view I want to set the height as a percentage -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FFFF" />

    <!-- My list view -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here i have added the Main LinearLayout and child all as Relative Layout with Percentage as weight of Screen.

Comment: I tried using linear layout, but I cannot use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" with a linear layout. The whole point is that the view needs to be at the bottom of the screen, not underneath the list view.

Comment: Please check the Answer Is it usable for you.

Comment: It might be close. I see a gray view at the bottom, but not a blue one.

Comment: Ok Let me try Please Provide in detail which type you want.

Comment: Okay, It works! I moved `android:background="#00FFFF"` as a view parameter to a layout parameter.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding what percentage of the screen the view takes. I see 0.8 and 1 which I don't understand how it adds up to 100%

Comment: Here you can expect as 1 means 100 and 0.8 means 80

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<View android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

with

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
       <View android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_top"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="#00FFFF"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I have assumed you want to fill 50% of the remaining space, and hence put layout_weight as 0.5. You may replace it with your required percentage.

Comment: I edited the xml, and put the view at the bottom and changed ID to `@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom` Is your solution still viable? It should be more clear now what I am trying to do. Sorry.

Comment: There is an error in your layouts. You have set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for 2 views, so they will overlap.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the xml in the question to incorporate your suggestion, but I still don't see the view at the bottom of the screen, nor at the bottom of the the list view as a matter of fact.

Comment: This is because you have set the height of the listview as match_parent. Set it to wrap_content.

Comment: Okay, I incorporated the change, but I still don't the see the view.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The orientation of LinearLayout defaults to horizontal if not specified. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91728/discussion-between-chitti-and-the-prole).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution on my own.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/listView1">

        <View android:id="@+id/rectangle_at_the_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00FFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```